# Clearing the textarea after using ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an working ajax function where the user types something in a textarea, press enter, and whatever the user types in, will be output to the screen. Right now I'm trying to find a way to clear the textarea after the user presses enter. How do I do that?

**test1.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajaxPass(gotoUrl,getValueFrom,output) {

      var input = document.getElementById(getValueFrom).value; // or $('#t').val();

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { input : input },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
           document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>

<textarea id = 'textarea' rows = "25" cols = "50" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) ajaxPass('robotChat2.php','textarea','output')"> </textarea>
<div id = 'output'> </div>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

$input = $_POST['input'];
echo $input;

?>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(getValueFrom).innerHTML = ''` right after you read the value

Comment: @developerwjk Right after document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;?

Comment: @developerwjk Also, why aren't you answering, instead of just commenting?

Comment: I meant right before the call to `$.ajax(` and I didn't think it was enough to bother with an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$("#textarea").val('');` at the end of your function.

```
    function ajaxPass(gotoUrl,getValueFrom,output) {

          var input = document.getElementById(getValueFrom).value; // or $('#t').val();

          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: gotoUrl,
               data: { input : input },
               error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
               success:function(data) {
               document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
               }

          });
            $("#"+getValueFrom).val('');
    }
```

Comment: Can I do  $("#getValueFrom").val(''); instead? I just want to pass it into the parameter, like so.

Comment: sure, so your text area id also shoul be `id=getValueFrom`

Comment: No. I mean, don't you see the getValueFrom in the function parameter?

Comment: @frosty you only need to assign the id there

Comment: @frosty no need to change anything. i have already assigned the id of text area. your text area id is `textarea`

Comment: @frosty you can also use this `$("#"+getValueFrom).val('');`
so if you assign id in ajaxpass function it will get the id